# SSRS 2005 to 2012 migration - microcharts

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2012, reporting-services, reporting

We have some reports created in SSRS 2005, which uses Bonavista Microcharts plugin to show microcharts.

We would like to upgrade the reports to SSRS 2012 now, but I couldnot add the XLCubed dll to SSRS report toolbox(which worked perfect in SSRS 2008). It is throwing an error saying "There are no components in this dll that can be placed on toolbox".

I can't even go back to Sparkline in SSRS 2012, because that would require a complete restructure of Dataset. The dataset is designed for Bonavista plugin, the microchart data is combined with a pipe (eg, 500|200|300 etc).

Any change in DS means we will have to make changes in around 300 reports, do we have any 3rd party microchart tool available for SSRS 2012, that is similar to XLCubed microcharts/Bonavista microcharts?

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at: [Nevron Chart for SSRS](http://www.microway.com.au/catalog/nevron/products.php)

Full disclosure: I'm in no way affiliated with Nevron

Comment: Thanks for that, Abhay. I wonder does Nevron chart supports Microcharts? I see only big Charts, Guages, Barcodes and maps.

Comment: I haven't used it personally, so I can't confirm whether it supports Microcharts. May be chatting with their support team might help.